# when i add another mesh, my icing goes wild.(explained with photos)

Tags: mesh

So i was doing my first donut, i wanted to add more sweet on it so i add a UV sphere and suddenly something enormous thing appeared(which is linked to my icing, if i delete that my icing goes too) along side the sphere.[image]  When i add bezier mesh it's look like this [image] how can i fix this?

so i went back to my old save and before adding random color to the sprinkles there was no problem. that thing i asked above happens after i add random colored sprinkles.

Comment: Can you share the blend file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your outliner, you will notice that your "*sprinkles*" collection icon is highlighted in white, and your bezier object was added inside that collection:

[image: outliner insert]

When you add an object into your scene, they are added into the "active collection", which is the one highlighted in white.
I reckon your particles system is set to use the objects in that collection, hence adding a Bézier curve object in here gives you that result.

To fix it: select your Bézier object, press M to move it into another collection.

To prevent the issue from there: click the icon of another collection to set it active.

Comment: thank you so much